# Adding Bootstrap component to navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Seems elementary, but I failed to add a span with Bootstrap component to my default navbar so that the components fits nicely into the navbar 
See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbekn1uk/) here. 
Is there any straightforward way to fix how the components fits into it ?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your CSS

```
.navbar-nav li{
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Check [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbekn1uk/1/)

Comment: because the bootstrap navbar minimum height is `50px` so we are giving the same height to its item.